# Не лишним ли здесь будет смысловое усиление?

Tags: запятые, выбор-слов, смысл, выбор-варианта, редактура

1. Это прекрасный агрегат. Он быстрый, но при этом, тихий (когда разработается). С ним Вы можете...
2. Это прекрасный агрегат. Он быстрый, но при этом, тихий одновременно (когда разработается). С ним Вы можете...

Какой вариант лучше? Все ли запятые расставлены верно?

Оригинальный вариант под номером 2, но меня терзают сомнения не лишним ли здесь выступает "одновременно"? Не заложено ли это "одновременно" уже в смысл фразы изначально? Нет ли здесь смыслового повторения?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: *Это прекрасный агрегат. **Он быстрый, но при этом тихий** (когда разработается).*

Одновременно — **лишнее слово.**

Союз НО здесь имеет **противительно-уступительное** значение, которое дополняется сочетанием "при этом". По смыслу "при этом" и "одновременно" совпадают.

Запятая не нужна, сочетание "при этом" относится к союзу НО.

**Примечание.** Значение уступки заключается в том, что ожидаемый признак "шумный" уступает место менее ожидаемому признаку "тихий".